# Rust starting a thread from an associated function

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a run associated method that would start a new thread and keep running there. The thread handle is saved in a struct property, but I get the following error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  --> src\server\dispatcher.rs:33:27
   |
28 |       pub fn run(&mut self) {
   |                  ---------
   |                  |
   |                  `self` is a reference that is only valid in the method body
   |                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
33 |           let main_thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
   |  ___________________________^
34 | |             match rx.try_recv() {
35 | |                 Ok(_) | Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
36 | |                     break;
...  |
43 | |             }
44 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`self` escapes the method body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
   |
```

My Code:

```
pub fn run(&mut self) {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<()>();

    let packets = Arc::new(Mutex::new((&self.packets)));

    let main_thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(_) | Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
                break;
            }
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {
                let inside = packets.clone();

                let qwe = packets.lock().unwrap();
            }
        }
    });

    self.main_thread = Some(main_thread);
}
```

Comment: You never use the `tx` side of the channel. Where are you planning to use it?

Comment: It will be used to notify the thread to stop. Probably saved into a struct property as well

Comment: Please add a complete [mre] i.e. remove any undefined types that are not necessary to reproduce the error (or if required to reproduce it add their definition).

Comment: The problem is that you are mutably borrowing `self`, and then borrowing `self.packets` in a new thread. The borrow checker doesn't know how long this thread will live, but the borrow of self is only valid for the function call. It's hard to offer a suggestion without knowing the broader context of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But, in general, trying to store everything in a single struct is going to make you have a bad time, if you are using threads. Think about how data is going to be used, and let that determine who owns it. e.g. if `packets` is only used in one thread then move it there. If `packets` is used in 2 threads then maybe share it through an `Arc` - sharing a _reference_ in an `Arc` is almost certainly not what you want to do!

Comment: which version of rust you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will probably use [thread::scope()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) in some way.

You are spawning a thread that captures `packets`, which contains a reference (pointer) to `self`. For all the compiler knows, your thread may still be running when the program ends, accessing `self` long after it has been freed.

If you instead spawn the thread from a scope, the compiler knows that it will be joined (waited for) when the scope ends. You can also send the stop signal at the end of the scope.

There are various options how to continue. You could create the scope outside and pass it to `run()`. Or you could pass an additional lambda to `run()` that contains the code you want to execute after creating the thread, so you don't have to store anything thread-specific into `self`. Or you could not use any references inside the thread, and have it own whatever it gets through the queue.

Comment: OP wants to "use [tx] to notify the thread to stop" probably at an arbitrary point in time that means using a scoped thread is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with associated functions.

`packets` captures a reference to `self.packets`. This is then moved into the thread. But you can't move references into a thread unless they refer to static data, because the thread might outlive whatever it's referencing.

Comment: So what would be the rustacean way of handling this? Save the arc mutex combo as a property on the struct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are borrowing `self.packets` in a new thread. The borrow checker doesn't know how long this thread will live, but the borrow of `self` is only valid for the current function call.

You didn't provide a full code sample but, simplifying a bit, perhaps this is representative:

```
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex, mpsc::*};
use std::thread;

struct Foo {
    packets: Vec<i32>
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn run(&mut self) -> (thread::JoinHandle<()>, mpsc::Sender<()>) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<()>();
        let packets = Arc::new(Mutex::new(&self.packets));
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            match rx.try_recv() {
                Ok(_) | Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
                    break;
                }
                Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {
                    let qwe = packets.lock().unwrap();
                }
            }
        });
        (handle, tx)
    }
}
```

By making the shared data an `Arc` on the struct field, there are no borrows - only clones of the `Arc`:

```
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex, mpsc::*};
use std::thread;

struct Foo {
    packets: Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn run(&mut self) -> (thread::JoinHandle<()>, mpsc::Sender<()>) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<()>();
        let packets = self.packets.clone();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            match rx.try_recv() {
                Ok(_) | Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => {
                    break;
                }
                Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {
                    let qwe = packets.lock().unwrap();
                }
            }
        });
        (handle, tx)
    }
}
```

This works because the thread is not borrowing anything from `self`.